# What type of game is Village idiot?

Tags: identify-this-game

I love to play Village Idiot (I'm sure it goes by other names, but I don't know them), and I am wanting to play games similar to it, mainly shorter games.  **Is there a definitive category or name that Village Idiot falls under**, which would help me in my search for similar games?

Here is a link to the rules to the version of the game I play: http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/310871

Comment: It would be good to include a quick summary of (or link to) the rules in the post itself, just in case there's more than one game out there with similar names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the rules I have seen, Village Idiot is one of a handful of [climbing card games](http://www.pagat.com/climbing/asshole.html). The most notable of these are The Great Dalmuti/Dilbert Corporate Shuffle.